# Identifying book set in 18th or 19th century France and England

Tags: identification-request

The main character is a young woman (late teens? early 20s?) She's in Paris with an (aunt?) and they're discussing what to do since her father has suddenly died. If they return to England, her brother will claim the family estate and sell it for gambling debts.  The only way she can see to prevent this is for her to marry someone, anyone, as soon as possible.  Before her brother learns of their father's death.  Does this sound familiar to anyone?

The book was written in English, maybe in the 1990s or 2000s. As best I can remember, if she married, her husband would then have the rights to the property. This was an era when women could not own property themselves, after all. Evidently she felt she could influence a husband to retain control. Where if she did nothing and let the inheritance pass to her brother, who cared nothing for the estate, he would sell it to pay gambling debts.

Comment: Any recollection of why their return to England had any bearing on what the brother, who was presumably the heir, would do? Or how her marriage would prevent her brother's inheriting?

Comment: So the story appears to be set in the 18th or 19th century. But do you have any idea when it may have been written and in which language?

Comment: not sure of when, but best guess 1990s or 2000s, and language = English.

Comment: Sounds like an imitation Georgette Heyer, or a Joan Aitken romance.

Comment: Spagirl: as best I can remember, if she married, her husband would then have the rights to the property. This was an era when women could not own property themselves, after all. Evidently she felt she could influence a husband to retain control.  Where if she did nothing and let the inheritance pass to her brother, who cared nothing for the estate, he would sell it to pay gambling debts.

Comment: @Magneto Women could own property, it wasn't *usual* to pass it down the distaff side if there is a male of the line is an option and if a man died intestate the eldest son legally inherited, but a father *could* leave heritable property to a daughter, or a widow could inherit.  But the bit I'm really not understanding is why her being outside of England could help rather than hinder her case, or how there could be any situation in which her *husband* could inherit in preference to or in tandem with her *brother*. So I thought those questions might help you remember plot details.

Comment: @Magneto Is there any chance it was a cousin rather than brother who was likely to sell the estate?